# SQL SELECT SUM from different Tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, conditional-statements, union

I have this SQL query that picks up some data between 2 dates:

```
SELECT sum(Line1) Line1, sum(Line2) Line2,sum(Line3) Line3, sum(Line4) Line4, sum(Line5) Line5, sum(Line6) Line6, 
sum(Line7) Line7, sum(Line8) Line8, sum(Line9) Line9, sum(Line10) Line10 FROM
[Sensor_1]
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '2018-08-17 00:00' AND '2018-08-17 23:59'
```

Basically, I have a Table called "Sensor_1" and I pick how many people goes through that Sensor. The thing is that there are more than one sensor, so I added ANOTHER Table for EACH Sensor, so if I want to pick the data from, for example, Sensor_2, I would do the same but Table = Sensor_2

Now, is there any way to put them all together?
I've thing in something like these but are not working:

```
SELECT sum(s1.Line1 + s2.Line1) ..., sum(s1.Line10 + s2.Line10) Line10 FROM
[Sensor_1] as s1, [Sensor_2] as s2
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '2018-08-17 00:00' AND '2018-08-17 23:59'
```

Or also

```
SELECT sum(Line1) Line1, ... , sum(Line10) Line10 FROM
(SELECT *
 FROM [Sensor_1]
 UNION
 SELECT *
 FROM [Sensor_2]
)
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '2018-08-17 00:00' AND '2018-08-17 23:59'
```

This is the database I'm using(SQLite): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1on_sSN_QM3FnPUcKo03iA3cE6uv1Y5uQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Select * from returns this data https://imgur.com/dmPm5vc

Comment: @Juanma Post format data instead of image that really help thank , and what's your expect result

Comment: My expected results is the SUM from 2 different Tables which have the same Columns in it

Since both Tables are really big, it's complicated to actually paste some data here. All the Tables have the same Columns, Line1, Line2... etc. I just want to combine them together

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Done it @GordonLinoff, here you have it

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1on_sSN_QM3FnPUcKo03iA3cE6uv1Y5uQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I would create a view to abstract the presence of many underling tables, so if sensors are added or removed, you just need to update this only view accordingly and have any derived query work seamlessly.

The view may be as simple as this:

```
create view Sensor_All as
   select 'sensor1' as sensor_name, *  from Sensor_1
   union all 
   select 'sensor2' as sensor_name, *  from Sensor_2
```

Beware, I've used `*` for simplicity, but you should name all columns to avoid column swaps.

I've also added a `sensor_name` column because it could be useful to have this information in some query later on.

Now you can create any query you like using the `Sensor_All` view, and your query will become as simple as

```
SELECT sum(Line1), sum(Line2) FROM
[Sensor_All]
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '2018-08-17 00:00' AND '2018-08-17 23:59'
```

Comment: Thats a very good idea since I'll need to add more Sensors in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your second query should work with `union all`.  I would list the columns explicitly:

```
select sum(Line1) as Line1, ... , sum(Line10) as Line10
from ((select timestamp, line1, line2, . . .
       from sensor_1
      ) union all
      (select timestamp, line1, line2, . . .
       from sensor_2
      )
     ) s
where TimeStamp >= '2018-08-17' and
      TimeStamp < '2018-08-18';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It seems it throws this exception:

ErrorCode : 1
Message   : SQL logic error
near "UNION": syntax error
Result    : Error

Comment: @juanma . . . Perhaps if you remove the parentheses around the subqueries.  A database or two don't like those parentheses.

Comment: Finally made it @gordon. I needed to add the "WHERE" condition for both SELECT tables

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to made it just by adding the condition for Both Tables, like this:

```
SELECT sum(Line1) AS Line1, ... ,  sum(Line10) AS Line10
FROM (
    SELECT Line1, ... , Line10
    FROM Sensor_1
    WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '2018-08-17 00:00' AND '2018-08-17 23:59'
UNION ALL
    SELECT Line1, ... , Line10
    FROM Sensor_2
    WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '2018-08-17 00:00' AND '2018-08-17 23:59'
    )
```